# Error converting string to int with int()

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm using Flask to write a very basic API. All it should do is get the string from the URI, convert it to an integer, multiply it by 1000 to go from seconds to milliseconds, add it to the current time in milliseconds, and parse the output in time format.

Here is the code I have so far for converting seconds to milliseconds:

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for

@app.route('/api/<seconds>')
    def api_seconds(seconds):
    milliseconds = int(seconds) * 1000
    return 'Seconds: ' + seconds + '\n' + 'Milliseconds: ' + milliseconds
```

This returns an Internal Server Error. When I remove the milliseconds variable completely and just use seconds, it works fine. According to the Flask page, `@app.route('api/<int:seconds>')` should return the string as an integer and I could just omit the `int(seconds)`. However, this also returns an Internal Server Error.

Also, `'\n'` isn't creating a new line for me.

Comment: Does Flask allow you to concatenate strings with integers? You should have to do `str(milliseconds)` in the `return` statement.

Comment: You can't just concatenate a string and int together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings with integers. Convert the integer to a string before concatenation.

```
return 'Seconds: ' + seconds + '\n' + 'Milliseconds: ' + str(milliseconds)
                                                         ^
```

Alternatively, you can use string formatting, which takes care of that for you:

```
return 'Seconds: {}\nMilliseconds: {}'.format(seconds, milliseconds)
```

Since you're working with the Flask framework and will be displaying this as HTML in a browser, you'll need to use an appropriate line break like `<br />`:

```
return 'Seconds: {}<br />Milliseconds: {}'.format(seconds, milliseconds)
```

Comment: Thanks, `str(milliseconds)` worked. Any idea why `'\n'` doesn't create a new line?

Comment: I do have an idea, but it's a shot in the dark that probably won't help: try using `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Or, since Flask is apparently a web framework and therefore might be rendered in a browser, try replacing `\n` with `<br />`.

Comment: Aha! `<br />` did the trick. Didn't even think of that. Thanks for your help.